# How to handle the result of an http request?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jsonparser

I am sending an HTTP request using XMLHttpRequest (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

The code is as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

    if(this.readyState === 4) {

        if(this.responseText.length > 0) {

            console.log(typeof this.responseText); //"string"
            var textToken = this.responseText;
            var objToken = JSON.parse(textToken);

            if(typeof objToken === 'object') {
            ---------
            } else if (typeof objToken === 'string') {
            ---------
            }

        } else {---}
    }
});
```

The response of the HTTP request, this.responseText will always be a string. But it can come in two forms:

1: `"{"prop": "value", "prop": "value"}"`

2: `"akduchkqlpouelqw"`

Currently I get the string converted to an object by JSON.parse(); but there is a possibility that this.responseText is a string like case number 2 above.

I would like to have the possibility that if this.responseText is option two, it would go into `(typeof objToken === 'string')`.

I have tried this manually by giving a value to `var textToken === 'akduchkqlpouelqw'`. In that case, if I change `(typeof objToken === 'string')` to `(typeof textToken === 'string')`, it's work.

But I have not been able to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse will fail if you passing a string as parameter, you can use a try catch

```js
const textToken = 'string';
try{
  const j = JSON.parse(textToken);
} catch {
  console.log('Hi! im a string')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof textToken === 'object') {
  var objToken = JSON.parse(textToken);
} else {
  console.log('this is string');
}
```